# How to add a total (int) field in my JSON response API

Tags: javascript, json, express

I'm developing an API with Express.js. In a getAll function I want to return an array of records but also the total number of records. This is the response I'm returning:

```js
const users = await User.getAll()
const total = users.length
const response = users
return res.json(response).status(200)
```

That has this format `[{user1},{user2},{user3}]`. How I can append the total with this format `{ data: {Record[]}, total: {int} }`?

I tried this but it adds a key in every user with its ordinal.

```js
const users = await User.getAll()
const total = users.length
const response = {
  ...users,
  total
}
return res.json(response).status(200)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const users = await User.getAll();
return res.json({ data: users, total: users.length }).status(200);
```

Comment: I was hooked with the spread operator I don't why, thank you, that totally works as expected

Answer (score 0):

You're using array spreading in an object with the line:

```js
const response = {
    ...users,
    total,
}
```

By doing this, you're trying to add all the elements of the array to an object, which isn't possible. But you can use the format you suggested yourself:

```js
const response = {
    data: users,
    total: total,
}

return res.json(response).status(200);
```

Answer (score 0):

`...users` is causing the pain here. When you use spread operator, It allows an iterable(here your `users` object) to expand. Below should work the way u expected.

```
const users = await User.getAll()
const total = users.length
const response = {
  users,
  total
}
return res.json(response).status(200)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the spread operator(...). The user's array is expanded in the response object. You can try the following code:

```
const users = await User.getAll()
const total = users.length
const response = {
  data: users,
  total,
}
return res.status(200).json(response)
```